# Why is Python for loop returning last element in each pass?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question title isn't quite correct but the code below should be clear enough.

```
instances = []
inst = {}
for i in range(4):
    print i
    inst['count'] = i
    instances.append(inst)
print instances
```

results in

```
0
1
2
3
[{'count': 3}, {'count': 3}, {'count': 3}, {'count': 3}]
```

I'm expecting

```
[{'count': 0}, {'count': 1}, {'count': 2}, {'count': 3}]
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: You put the same dictionary in your list four times.

Comment: @khelwood: Why did the dictionary not update?

Comment: The dictionary is updating. But you wouldn't want the same dictionary to update, you'd want to create different dictionaries which you'd get by doing `inst = {}` in the for loop.

Comment: You keep mutating the same `dict`. `instances.append(inst)` doesn't *copy* the dict into the list, it just adds the same reference to the list. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @MarioIshac: OK, moving `inst = {}` into the loop fixes it, thanks. I'll study some more ...

Comment: @chepner: Thank you for the link. I'll have a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what's happening here is that the dictionary you are trying to update is a runtime variable at this point, and every time it gets updated in the for loop, it is also updating the value of the item present in it so that the final output is the same where ever this variable is present. *Considering values in both list and dict are not hardcoded values but dynamic in nature.*

It can simply be fixed by creating an empty dict at every iteration. So it does not overwrite the same location in memory, and unique values are captured.

```
instances = []

for i in range(4):
    inst = {}
    print i
    inst['count'] = i
    instances.append(inst)
print instances
```

Comment: I've got your question released. I think the reason for the downvote by moderators is because of lack of research.

Answer (score 0):

Place the definition of the `inst` variable inside the loop.

```
instances = []
for i in range(4):
    inst = {}
    inst['count'] = i
    instances.append(inst)
print(instances)
```

Comment: You should also explain why this behavior is different so that OP understands for the future.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mario Ishac said the declaration of your dict is done before the for loop so you are working on the same dictionnary. Add it within your for loop. I have tested and that works.

```
instances = []
for i in range(4):
    inst = {}
    print(i)
    inst['count'] = i
    instances.append(inst)
print(instances)
```